# Thread.Sleep never returns

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, gtk#

I have an application that draws somethong on a form (just a test application). I faced a problem with Thread.Sleep. I use thread that initiates DrawinArea repaint every 100 milliseconds. It works fine, but sometimes this thread cannot return from This.Sleep(100) call. I've checked in the debugger, and I'm sure that problem is in Thread.Sleep().

Attention: it requires Gtk# to run.

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using Cairo;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{

    Thread redrawThread = new Thread(Redrawer);

    //System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    static int calls = 0;

    public MainWindow()
        : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build();
        this.drawingarea2.ExposeEvent += OnExpose;

        redrawThread.Name = "Redraw Thread";

        redrawThread.Start(this);
        /*
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            drawingarea2.QueueDraw();
        };
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();*/

    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        redrawThread.Abort();
        Application.Quit();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }


    static void Redrawer(object wnd) {
        var area = (MainWindow)wnd;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            area.QueueDraw();
        }
    }

    int x = 200;
    int x_mod = 10;
    int y = 150;
    int y_mod = 10;



    void OnExpose(object sender, ExposeEventArgs args) {

        var area = (DrawingArea)sender;

        if (x + 10 >= drawingarea2.Allocation.Width || x - 10 < 0)
            x_mod = -x_mod;

        if (y + 10 >= drawingarea2.Allocation.Height || y - 10 < 0)
            y_mod = -y_mod;

        x += x_mod;
        y += y_mod;

        var ny = Math.Abs(y - drawingarea2.Allocation.Height);

        using (var ctx = Gdk.CairoHelper.Create(area.GdkWindow))
        {


            ctx.LineWidth = 9;
            ctx.SetSourceRGB(0.7, 0.2, 0.0);

            ctx.Arc(x, ny, 10, 0, 2*Math.PI);
            ctx.StrokePreserve();

            ctx.SetSourceRGB(0.3, 0.4, 0.6);
            ctx.Fill();

            ctx.GetTarget().Dispose();
        }


    }

}
```

Once faced this problem I decided to switch to System.Timers.Timer, but I've also faced a problem with it. Timer stops firing event after some time. I searched for this problem and found that GC can destroy timer if there are no references to it. My timer is a class member, so reference always exists, but in any case, it stops. What is the problem?

Comment: I can not think of a single thing GTK# could do that would prevent a `Thread.Sleep` call from returning. You said you are sure it is the sleep call, how *specifically* did you use the debugger to go about find that out?

Comment: First, never use `thread.Sleep` for UI threads.  As you mentioned in question, switch to *timer* route and ask your problem.

Comment: @L.B Thread.Sleep is not used in UI thread, it is used in parallel one that makes UI to redraw. UI is always responsive in my case.

Comment: @Scott, I set a name to my thread and after I see that problem to occur I pause application and look through threads list in VS and see that this thread is inside Thread.Sleep call. Also, I used a kind of messages to indicate execution steps, message inserted before Thread.Sleep were shown and those inserted after it - not.

Comment: That just shows that when you hit pause it was in the sleep call, not that it was stuck in the sleep call. Having `area.QueueDraw();` stop functioning even though you called it would give you the same behavior. Also what "kind of messages" did you use and how did you read the output? If you put a breakpoint on the QueueDraw call when it is "stuck" in the sleep call does the breakpoint get hit?

Comment: @Xanx I've never worked with gtk#, but in Winforms you can not update the UI controls in background threads, same can be true for gtk#.

Comment: @L.B I know about that feature of WinForms, but in gtk# it seems to work. Ok, but why timer do not work also? AFAIK its Elapsed event is called in context of the thread that owns it.

Comment: @L.B from peeking at the documentation `QueueDraw` would be like doing a `area.BeginInvoke(() => area.Invalidate())` if this was winforms. EDIT: AND OMG I think I figured it out... writing a answer

Comment: @Scott, I've just updated window title before and after sleep. And the last change I saw was before sleep message.

Comment: Functionality provided essentially by system calls, eg 'Thread.Sleep().' are EXTREMELY unlikely to have serious bugs.  They've had too much testing by billions of users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of `QueueDraw()` it stated

> Equivalent to calling Widget.QueueDrawArea for the entire area of a widget.

Reading the documentation for `QueueDrawArea` it states

> Invalidates the rectangular area of widget [...]. Once the main loop becomes idle (after the current batch of events has been processed, roughly), the window will receive Widget.ExposeEvent events for the union of all regions that have been invalidated.

What is happening is every 100ms you are putting another message on the queue for the main window and the main window is taking longer than 100ms to process this request. Because you are producing redraw requests faster than it can fulfill redraw requests this is flooding the queue and once it reaches its max size no new messages can be received and it "locks up".

When you stated  you tested this by updating the window's title that update would also need to go on to the queue to get done, however because the queue is full those title changes never showed up. Sleep was not hanging, it was just your debugging method was broken due to the same underlying problem.

The solution is call `QueueDraw()` less often.

Comment: I've increased interval and it seems to work! Thank you! I've wasted the whole day for this and dont't know why I haven't figured it out myself.

Comment: @Xanx, you may want to implement some sort of adaptive throttling for this to avoid cases where heavy transient computer load still locks the thread permanently.

Comment: The whole `Redrawer` method reeks of code smell to me, I am not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish but I am sure there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Well, I need to simulate a process showing its graphical representation. Every 100 ms I calculate process state and then draw it on a drawing area.